# Why lambda expression has no return value?

Tags: c#, lambda

I read a code to send a email,here part of it:

```
MailUserState state = new MailUserState()
{
    AutoReleaseSmtp = m_autoDisposeSmtp,
    CurMailMessage = mMailMessage,
    CurSmtpClient = m_SmtpClient,
    IsSmpleMail = true,
    UserState = AsycUserState,
};
if (m_autoDisposeSmtp)
  m_SmtpClient = null;

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem((userState) =>
{
    MailUserState curUserState = userState as MailUserState;
    curUserState.CurSmtpClient.SendAsync(mMailMessage, userState);
}, state);
```

Why the lambda expression has no return value?

I think it shoud return a `callback` instance object.But it has no return statement.Why?

Comment: Where would it return the value to? What would the thread pool do with the return value?

Comment: The QueueUserWorkItem function has two parameters.

Comment: The lambda expression _is_ a WaitCallback instance (or convertible to one, anyway). It doesn't need to return one.

Comment: I don't known too much about thread

Comment: @Dolphin, the QueueUserWorkItem function has two overloads, one of which takes two parameters.

Comment: @Dolphin: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kbf0f1ct(v=vs.110).aspx ?

Comment: Oh,i know.The first parameter was the function the thread execute.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Why the lambda expression has no return value?

The first argument of the [`ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yd16hza%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method is a [`WaitCallback`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.waitcallback%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) delegate which looks like this:

```
public delegate void WaitCallback(object state)
```

So as you can see it is a function taking one object parameter and having no return value. And that's exactly what the lambda expression in your code is. The `QueueUserWorkItem` method will draw a thread from the thread pool if/when available and it will execute the code in the callback on this thread. There is no return value.